# Using " - interval 5 HOUR" getting error with Having Clause

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT
    `cid`.`CHECK_IN_DETAILS_ID` AS `CHECK_IN_DETAILS_ID`,
    CONCAT(
        `lvdu`.`FIRST_NAME`,
        ' ',
        `lvdu`.`LAST_NAME`
    ) AS `FULL_NAME`,
    `cid`.`CHECK_IN_TIME` - INTERVAL 5 HOUR AS `CHECK_IN_TIME`,
    `cod`.`CHECK_OUT_TIME` - INTERVAL 5 HOUR AS `CHECK_OUT_TIME`,
    COUNT(
        IF(
            (`tad`.`TRIP_STATUS` = 'Completed'),
            1,
            NULL
        )
    ) AS `NUM_OF_COMPLETED_TRIP_ASSIGNMENTS`,
    COUNT(
        IF(
            (`tad`.`TRIP_STATUS` = 'In Progress'),
            1,
            NULL
        )
    ) AS `NUM_OF_INPROGRESS_TRIP_ASSIGNMENTS`,
    COUNT(
        IF(
            (
                (`tad`.`TRIP_STATUS` = 'Assigned') OR(`tad`.`TRIP_STATUS` = 'Accepted')
            ),
            1,
            NULL
        )
    ) AS `NUM_OF_ASSIGNED_NOT_COMPLETE_TRIP_ASSIGNMENTS`,
    IF(
        (
            (`cid`.`CHECK_IN_TIME` IS NOT NULL) AND(`cod`.`CHECK_OUT_TIME` IS NOT NULL)
        ),
        IF(
            (
                (
                    TIME_TO_SEC(
                        TIMEDIFF(
                            `cod`.`CHECK_OUT_TIME`,
                            `cid`.`CHECK_IN_TIME`
                        )
                    ) / 3600
                ) < `cid`.`HOURS_REMAINING`
            ),
            'Y',
            'N'
        ),
        'driver have not check out yet'
    ) AS `INCOMPLETE_DAY`
FROM
    (
        (
            (
                (
                    `Appian`.`LDA_CHECK_IN_DETAILS` `cid`
                LEFT JOIN `Appian`.`LDA_CHECK_OUT_DETAILS` `cod`
                ON
                    (
                        (
                            `cid`.`CHECK_IN_DETAILS_ID` = `cod`.`CHECK_IN_DETAILS_ID`
                        )
                    )
                )
            LEFT JOIN `Appian`.`LDA_VIEW_DRIVER_AND_USER_DETAILS` `lvdu`
            ON
                (
                    (
                        `cid`.`DRIVER_DETAILS_ID` = `lvdu`.`DRIVER_DETAILS_ID`
                    )
                )
            )
        LEFT JOIN `Appian`.`LDA_SCHEDULE_DETAILS` `sd`
        ON
            (
                (
                    `cid`.`DRIVER_DETAILS_ID` = `sd`.`DRIVER_DETAILS_ID`
                )
            )
        )
    LEFT JOIN `Appian`.`LDA_TRIP_ASSIGNMENT_DETAILS` `tad`
    ON
        (
            (
                `cid`.`CHECK_IN_DETAILS_ID` = `tad`.`CHECK_IN_DETAILS_ID`
            )
        )
    )
GROUP BY
    `cid`.`CHECK_IN_DETAILS_ID`
HAVING
    (
        (
            (
                `cid`.`CHECK_IN_TIME` >(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND(
                    `cod`.`CHECK_OUT_TIME` >(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY))
                ) OR(
                    (
                        `cod`.`CHECK_OUT_TIME` >(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND(
                            `cid`.`CHECK_IN_TIME` <(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY))
                        ) OR(
                            (
                                `cid`.`CHECK_IN_TIME` >(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AND ISNULL(`cod`.`CHECK_OUT_TIME`)
                            )
                        )
```

It keeps returning me the issue of Having Clause unknown column `cid`.`CHECK_IN_TIME`. Once I removed "- INTERVAL 5 HOUR" from select clause, it works fine. Seems like that "- INTERVAL 5 HOUR" is not acceptable in this query. But it is just select clause right?

Can anyone answer my question?

Comment: If this is simple, I dread to think what one of your more complex queries looks like.  Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Statement A: `cid.check_in_time > now() - interval 1 day`. Statement B: `cod.check_out_time > now() - interval 1 day`. Can a situation occur where statement A is true and Statement B is false?

Comment: This is a consequence of incomplete grouping. Add `cid.CHECK_IN_TIME - INTERVAL 5 HOUR` and `cid.CHECK_OUT_TIME - INTERVAL 5 HOUR` to GROUP BY expression.

Comment: Note that the test for overlaps is as follows: Event A overlaps Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts.

Comment: I solved the issue by using nest query: SELECT result.*, result.* ,result.time - 5 HOUR from select ( this query) as result. But I don't understand why I have to do this, why I cannot just minus 5 hours from the select clause?